# Special color-markup for angular-templates in sublime text?

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext2

I'm looking for a syntax-markup for angularJS. Stuff like:

- Special coloring of double curlybraces `{{mytag}}`
- Special coloring of any attribute starting with `ng-`...

I already tried [this package](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package). It has html(angular) syntax, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Why don't you create your own color scheme ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even concider that I could, I should look into that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tweaked HTML.tmlanguage file bit to do something like that.

[image: HTML(angularjs).tmLanguage]

you can download the file from my [SublimeText2-Userfiles repo on GitHub](https://github.com/aziz/sublimeText2-Userfiles/blob/master/Syntaxes/HTML%20%28Angular.js%29.tmLanguage)

Here is how to use it:

- Copy the file to your user folder and then while you've an angular.js template file open, click on the Syntax option in bottom right corner of sublime text status bar. select User>HTML (Angular.js)
- You should also update you color scheme to add color highlighting for angular specific scopes. you can checkout [my personal color-scheme on the same repo here](https://github.com/aziz/sublimeText2-Userfiles/blob/master/Color%20Schemes/PlasticCodeWrap.tmTheme). I think all you need is something like this.

  ```
          <dict>
                  <key>name</key>
                  <string>Angular</string>
                  <key>scope</key>
                  <string>entity.other.attribute-name.angular.html, source.angular.embedded.html</string>
                  <key>settings</key>
                  <dict>
                          <key>foreground</key>
                          <string>#FF3A83</string>
                  </dict>
          </dict>
  ```

Remember it's just a dirty hack to make my personal workflow easier. I would appreciate if you contribute and make it better. It needs a lot of improvements but it's almost all that you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for great work. This really useful, but can you help me with the scope for curly-brackets? Because it apply for the CSS inline. Just need the Regex for apply only when there is `'` or `"` before and after. And also the name of that scope.

Comment: Fantastic, works great! @LinhPham -- not sure what you're referring to. Inline styles seem unaffected.